# Python 2.7.11 Pip 8.0.3 can't install gohike WHL of TA-Lib 0.4.9

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pip, ta-lib

A random pip update of numpy caused other modules(pandas) to 'break' and further updates(distutils,setuptools) I think broke pip somehow.  I deleted pip and all python's and directories and reinstalled python.  'pip install module' works and numpy compiled in pip automatically using visual c++.  I have all the other modules I need reinstalled except for ta-lib.

I had ta-lib working and installed through pip/gohike before the update fiasco but afterwards pip still isn't working.  I know the python ta-lib module is a python wrapper for the ta-lib library which is a c library.  I have the library downloaded but don't know how to compile it and I think it would be easier to get the .whl working(which I'm sure includes the compiled c library as I've had it working before).  But help with either method of installation would be appreciated.

When I try using pip I get the error:
talib\common.c(248) : fatal error c1083: Cannot open include file: 'ta_libc.h': No such file or directory

Which I think is because the c library isn't compiled thought I did unzip it and place it in c:\ta-lib which is the best instructions I could find.
https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib

When I try the .whl file,http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#ta-lib. From the download directory I do 'pip install TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp27-none-win_amd64.WHL' I get:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\owner\appdata\local\temp\pip-dvkuf9-build\setup.py'

If it helps, before uninstalling python/pip I was getting these errors from pip: setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1.

Thanks to anyone who can help me sort out this multi-day headache!

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html)? I just followed the instructions by doing `brew install ta-lib` on my Mac, then `pip install ta-lib` in my virtual environment and had no problems. If you're on Linux, I'd try `sudo apt-get install ta-lib` or `yum install ta-lib` before doing the `pip install`. I unfortunately don't have much experience with these libraries on Windows.

Comment: Ya, I've looked there and all over.  I'm wondering if anyone can provide me with the windows installer that gohike published before switching to wheel?

Comment: It's clearly a Windows issue. I installed the latest versions of numpy and pandas on Ubuntu within the last week or so with no problems.