# pip wont install .WHL files

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install any .WHL from gohike by typing into the cmd `C:\Users\owner\Downloads>pip install TA_Lib-0.4.9-cp27-none-win_amd64.WHL`I get this print out:

```
`Processing c:\users\owner\downloads\ta_lib-0.4.9-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback <most recent call last>:
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'c:\\users\\owner\\appdata\\lo
cal\\temp\\pip-9gwk2c-build\\setup.py'
    -----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\owner\ap
pdata\local\temp\pip-9gwk2c-build\`
```

The part between pip- and -build in`pip-9gwk2c-build` is always different even on the same file.

I asked this [Python 2.7.11 Pip 8.0.3 can't install gohike WHL of TA-Lib 0.4.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35811104/python-2-7-11-pip-8-0-3-cant-install-gohike-whl-of-ta-lib-0-4-9) a few days ago and decided to ask differently.  Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Comment: Check if you have the `setup.py` in the `pip-9gwk2c-build` folder

Comment: Check your pip version

Comment: @TonyRoczz wheels do **not** have a setup.py.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I asked to check since the error log says `No such file or directory` in the temp directory

Comment: Of course you asked, the answer is "no", there is no setup.py in that temp directory.

Comment: In the directory is: 'pip-egg-info' 'TA_Lib-0.4.9.dist-info' 'talib' 'pip-delete-this-directory'

Answer (score 1):

You have an outdated `pip` which does not understand wheels. Wheels are not even supposed to have a `setup.py` inside.

Try upgrading pip with `pip install --upgrade pip` and then running the command again.

Comment: My pip is up to date, 8.1.0.

Comment: Interesting indeed. Unfortunately I do not have a windows machine to test further.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't fix pip but I found out that if I use 7zip to open/unpack the wheel file and drag drop the 2 folders in it into C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages that it works!